# PostgreSQL error Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)

Tags: python, postgresql, aiogram

Trying to launch telegram bot (aiogram) and connected DB on PostgreSQL

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: connection to server at "127.0.0.1", port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I assume that this is due to the fact that the bot and b are trying to connect to the same local IP

Comment: It says that there is no postgresql instance running in the 5432 port, you changed the port or the postgresql is not running

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your Postgres service, it could be in a stopped state

If you are running on Ubuntu
Try `sudo service postgresql restart`